# How can I determine if a number is a part of arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Sorry if this is a simple question, I am not so good in mathematics and trying to start understanding it better. So thanks in advance.

I have this sequence - $0,1,5,6,10,11,15,16,20,21$....
Which is $n$ numbers and then a gap of $n+1$.
What I need is a way to get a random number and check if it is part of the sequence.

I see that I can check the last number and see if it is $(0,1,5,6)$ but this will be true only for this sequence. So I need more generic way.

Thanks
Shani

**edit**
The sequence starts from $0$
$n = 2$
Then we start with $n$ numbers $(0,1)$ skip $n+1$ numbers $(2,3,4)$ then include $n$ numbers $(5,6)$ , skip $n+1$ $(7,8,9)...$

Comment: I know the sequence it is in this case n and then a gap of n+1. Thanks

Comment: i don't understand the definition of the sequence.  You say "$n$ numbers and then a gap of $n+1$"  but your sequence looks like $2$ numbers and then a gap of $4$.  What is $n$?  Can you write out the first few terms if $n$ were, say, $3$?

Comment: Ok.  Edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Got it.  So, in this case, the "consecutive strings" start with elements of the progression $\{0,5,10,15,\dots\}$.   Given a random $m$ find the nearest multiple of $5$ less than or equal to $m$....then we need $m$ to either be this multiple or $1$ greater.  Similar for general $n$.

Comment: The terms of an [arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) have a common difference, so this is not an arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Okay generally speaking you *need* to have a formula for the terms of the sequence. In your case the formula *seems* to be
$$a_{2n} = 5n\; , \; a_{2n+1} = 5n+1$$
However it might as well be a completely different formula, this is completely possible!

The basic notion is to try and find the relations between the terms and express them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of your sequence is perhaps not very practical when it comes to calculations. But the procedure for producing elements of the sequence is a periodic one. You take an input sequence of natural numbers and pick two and then skips $n$ and repeat. This means that you consume $n+2$ integers from the input sequence for each round through the algorithm.

You can reformulate the produce by working in chunks. You take a chunk of $n+2$ integers and emit the first two.

Now it shouldn't be too hard to see that the $(j+1)$th chunk consist of the numbers $(n+2)j, (n+2)j+1, \dots, (n+2)j+n+1$ of which we pick the first two numbers. This results in that we see that the numbers we produce is $(n+2)j$ and $(n+2)j+1$.

So the question is transformed to the question whether a random number $r$ can be written as $r = (n+2)j$ or $r-1=(n+2)j$ for some integer $j$. That is if $r/(n+2)$ or $(r-1)/(n+2)$ are integers (we call that $r$ or $r-1$ is divisible by $n+2$).